# Complex Logarithm Difference

Tags: complex-numbers

We know that $\log z = \log\vert z\vert + i\arg(z)$. $\log z$ and $\log\vert z\vert$ are only different by a **bounded function**. (More specifically by $i\pi$ since $\vert i\arg(z)\vert\le\pi.)$

Now however I'm interested in the case
$$\log(1+c\vert z\vert ^2)\quad\text{and}\quad \vert \log(1+c z ^2)\vert,$$
where $c$ is a positive real number and $z$ complex, more spefically in the right half plane. Now I wonder if these two also only differ by a constant (or a bounded funcction) and if this is the case, how I can prove it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Consider the difference between the two:

$$\begin{eqnarray} \log(1 + cz^2) - \log(1 + c|z|^2) & = & \log|1 + cz^2| + i \arg(1 + cz^2) - \log(1 + c|z|^2) \\
& = & i \arg(1 + cz^2) + \log \left(\frac{|1 + cz^2|}{1 + c|z|^2} \right)
\end{eqnarray}$$

If we then look at the fraction within the logarithm, the denominator is always going to be $\geq 1$, but as $z^2 \rightarrow \frac{1}{c}$, the numerator is going to approach zero, meaning that we can make the whole thing arbitrarily small, and so when we take the logarithm it will tend towards negative infinity.